# Is it possible to check only part of a primary key in postgres when using ON CONFLICT

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

Have a table in postgres

```
attr_id uuid not null,
item_id uuid not null,
common_value varchar(100) not null,
int_value int,
primary key(attr_id, item_id, common_value)
```

Can have 2 types of inserts one when int_value can be different for pair attr_id-item_id and one when there should be single value for int_value for pair attr_id-item_id

So I want to check them with on conflict like so

```
On Conflict (attr_id, item_id, common_value) for multiple values
On Conflict (attr_id, item_id) for single value
```

Ofcourse it doesn't work for single value with primary key(attr_id, item_id, common_value) )))

Is there any way to achieve this through indexes or constraints may be or any other way other then splitting table on 2?

Thanks in advance for answers ;)

Comment: No, not possible. The `on conflict()` clause must either references a unique constraint by name or **all** columns of a unique constraint

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine offered solution.

add column

```
is_single bool default false
```

then create index like this

```
create unique index single_idx on table_name(attr_id, item_id) where is_single;
```

and then we change (on conflict) for single value like this:

```
OnConflict("(attr_id, item_id) where is_single DO UPDATE")
```

And it worked. Tests passed no problem. No errors, no duplicates for multi values and single ones change as they are supposed to